# Where can I find a food/mineral/rare item maniac?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I have a loads of items that fall into those categories. However I cannot find the buyers.

Does anyone know where these item maniacs are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no item maniacs in Pokémon X and Y.

Comment: If there are no maniacs then why does the tiny mushrooms etc. still say about collectors?

Comment: I have no idea.

Comment: Maybe you will find some usefull information [Here](http://www.marriland.com/forums/pokemon-6th-generation/pokemon-x-y/448856-q-are-there-rare-item-collectors-in-x-y)

Comment: Thank you. I will try the link on a different computer at another time as this computer doesn't seem to be able to access it.